# Циклы и прочие штуки, взятые в { ... }

Tags: c, c++

Здравствуйте! Волнует такой вопрос. Есть в с++ такие вот скобки {}. Если в методе, в них объявить переменную как тут:

```
void funct(){
int g=0;
  {
     int g=0;
  }
}
```

то компилятор не будет ругаться. Почему? Если объяснить на языке ассемблера то что произойдет? Произойдет вызов функции с передачей всех переменных доступных верхней функции в {}? если да, то как передадутся переменные, в стеке? Для чего вообще может быть допустима приведенная выше конструкция? И вот еще. Вот этот символ ";" означает конец операции, например `int t=a+b;`. А что он выполняет? почему его можно ставить так:

```
void f(){
;
} или 
 void f(){ };
```

и ошибки не будет? Что делает компьютер, когда натыкается на ;?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`{....}` - это блок кода и он может быть вставлен везде, где можно вставить одиночную строку. Вас ведь  не смущает код:

```
if (....)
   doSmth();
```

и

```
if (....) {
   doSmth();
}
```

Но у этих скобок есть одна особенность - они объявляют новую область видимости.

```
void funct(){
int g=0;
  {
     int g=0; // это другая переменная g, она имеет другой адрес!
     // предыдущая g не доступна по своему имени до закрывающей фигурной скобки.
  }
  // а здесь снова доступна первая переменная.
}
```

На уровне ассемблера это выглядит так

```
funct():
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0 ; первая g
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0 ; вторая g
    pop rbp
    ret
```

> как передадутся переменные, в стеке?

как обычно. Хотя никто не мешает компилятору проанализировать и сделать хорошо.

> Для чего вообще может быть допустима приведенная выше конструкция?

например для любителей длинных функций, когда хочется добавить ещё сотню строк, а переменные (имена) закончились.

Но если серьезно, то подобные конструкции используются постоянно - циклы, условия.

> Вот этот символ ";" означает конец операции, например int t=a+b;. А что он выполняет?

он выполняет декоративную роль для программиста. Это синтаксический сахар. Но компилятор может пользоваться им в том случае, если в коде много ошибок, что бы хотя бы как то разделять операторы. Вот в Go точку с запятой можно пропускать, когда и так понятно, что она там должна быть.

В ассемблерном коде она никак не отображается.

Comment: Известно, что все локальные переменные выделяются на стеке. Но при этом при выходе из области видимости все принадлежащие ей переменные должны "грохнуться". И интересно как это будет выглядеть на ассемблере - ведь вряд ли для каждого блока кода будет выделяться свой стек.

Comment: выделятся свой стек не будет. В классическом случае компилятор просто выставит стек в нужный размер заранее. Если нужно, вставит вызовы деструкторов в нужных местах (по выходу с блока).

Если же рассматривать примитивный компилятор, то при входе в блок он будет запоминать текущий указатель на стек (самое смешное - запоминать его в стеке:) ), для каждой встреченной переменной увеличивать его (но по факту - вычитать размер размещаемого объекта). При выходе с блока - вызовы деструктора и восстановления старого указателя стека.

Comment: @KoVadim Хороший ответ, только вот ";" все же не сахар. В случае с++ компилятор, основываясь на ";" и других терминаторах, разбивает текст программы на операторы.
@gecube Стек один на поток, для каждой функции собирается сразу весь стекфрейм (во время компиляции) и когда ты попадаешь в функцию указатель стека смещается что бы поместить весь фрейм функции. А когда выходишь - возвращается назад. Стек между разными блоками {} внутри одной функции может шарится (быть общим).

Comment: @IronVbif я не даром упомянул о Go. Там компилятор считает, что в конце строки, если нужно, есть точка с запятой. Я к примеру, не вижу ничего плохого в таком коде

    #include <>
    int main()
    {
        int i
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           std::cout << i
           std::cout << '\n'
        }
        return 0
     }

Компилятор легко разрулит (если его допилить).

`;` раньше нужны были людям, что бы упросить и ускорить компилятор. Но сейчас есть много языков, которым `;` не нужна. Например, питон.

Поэтому, это сахар.

Comment: а как тогда ваш гипотетический компилятор разрулит код вида

    a
    *b

или

    for( i = 0;  i < 10;  i++, call_func() )
    another_func()

Вообще не корректно сравнивать плюсы с го и питоном, у них синтаксис вцелом проще, поэтому и можно додумывать и там точка с запятой похожа на сахар для человеского восприятия. С или С++ вы не скомпилите без них, потому что переводы строк игнорируются и ";" являются обязательными.

Comment: первый случай парситься просто. Вначале определяется, что `a` - это тип. (информация об этом на данный момент должна быть. `*b` тогда вычитывается автоматом. Нужно только одно ограничение - переменные не могут иметь имени, которое совпадает с именем типа (а это и так есть). Но можно поставить требование, что объявления должно быть в одну строку.

Второй случай парситься чуточку сложнее. Здесь объязательно должно быть соглашение. К примеру, for должен иметь тело с одного оператора в обязательном порядке. Если тело цикла не нужно, то можно поставить `{}` как тело. Или точку с запятой.

Comment: @IronVbif, ну это разруливается легко (только не всегда однозначно, поэтому я решительно против подобных нововведений (шутка, само собой их не будет)) если следовать такому правилу:

если следующая после '\\n' лексема приводит к синтаксической ошибке, то заменить '\n' на ';' и повторить анализ.

Comment: @KoVadim, по первому примеру Вы не совсем правы.
Ибо пользователь мог иметь в виду:

    a;*b; // две инструкции, но при этом a и b - или переменные, или ф-ции
    a *b; // b - указатель на a
    a*b;  // произведение a и b

А учитывая, что в С++ есть куча вроде перегрузки операторов и шаблонов, то что там должно было быть на самом деле становится тем более неочевидно.

Короче, это искусственные сложности какие-то получаются. С одной стороны действительно круто, когда язык имеет регулярную структуру, но тогда не дай Бог ее нарушить (пробел или табуляцию лишние вставить), а с другой стороны

Comment: С++ имеет такой сложный синтаксис, что его без поллитра иногда не разберешь, но обычно все пишут на каком-то его подмножестве, чтобы "индусам" было понятно, что имел в виду программист.

Comment: @gecube
Если просто смотреть на три выражения, то да, сложно. Но у компилятора есть дополнительная информация

    a;*b; // что бы это были функции, должны быть `()` Но компилятор 
    
    a * b

а этот случай разруливается просто. Если известно, что `a` - это тип, то все понятно. Если известно, что это переменная, тогда тоже понятно. Если a и b к этому моменту не определены, то значения комбинации этой последовательности не определено. Но какое тогда это имеет значение:)

Comment: @KoVadim В первом случае имеется ввиду не объявление переменной, а неоднозначность между тем, что это из двух: умножение или разыменование второй переменной. А вы свои новые правила для парсинга тоже сахаром считаете? 

@avp да, на простых примерах наверно сработает. Но если взять второй пример то получается что another_func() всегда будет приклеиваться к циклу, даже если программист хочет обратного.

Вообще все неоднозначности устраняет ";", а если она влияет на функциональность, значит она не сахарная получается.

Comment: Вот пример, где без разделителя [не обойтись](https://ideone.com/b8kLEn). Синтаксис C++ и правда намного сложнее практически _всех_ остальных языков.

Answer (score 4):

[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim) уже ответил про области видимости, хочу немного дополнить о распределении памяти (заодно ответ на комментарий [@gecube](/users/907/gecube)).

При входе в блок и выходе из него стек, естественно, не меняется. Компилятор определяет максимальный размер, который займут локальные переменные с учетом переменных локальных для блока и сдвигает регистр стека при входе в функцию на нужную величину.

Например в

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
foo ()
{
  int x = 0, y;
  printf("first local x = %d at %p\n", x, &x);

 b1:; // кстати, это (вопрос №2) называется пустой оператор
  {
    int x = 1, y1;
    printf("b1: block x = %d at %p\n", x, &x);
  }
  printf("second local x = %d at %p\n", x, &x);

 b2:; 
  {
    int x = 2, y2;
    printf("b2: block x = %d at %p\n", x, &x);
  }
  printf("last local x = %d at %p\n", x, &x);
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  foo();
  return puts("Bye!") == EOF;
}
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc foo.c
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
first local x = 0 at 0xbfcaf2f8
b1: block x = 1 at 0xbfcaf2fc
second local x = 0 at 0xbfcaf2f8
b2: block x = 2 at 0xbfcaf2fc
last local x = 0 at 0xbfcaf2f8
Bye!
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

видно, что переменые `x` в разных блоках размещаются по **одному и тому же адресу**.

Понятно, что когда компилятор встречает вот такое

```
int arr[x];
```

объявление локального массива (`x` это переменная, значение которой во время компиляции неизвестно), то он создает код, сдвигающий регистр sp (указатель стека) в данном месте, а при выходе из области видимости восстанавливает старое значение sp.